# How do I prevent the soft keyboard from pushing bottom bar for child activity when called from tabactivity?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-softkeyboard, tabactivity

I have a borrowed code of TabGroupActivity through which i call child activities within Tabactivity. My problem arises when i have a Edittext which when clicked shows softkeyboard pushing the bottom bar upward. This happens only for activities called from childactivity itself. It means, once the second level childactivity is launched that behaviour comes up and when tabs are switched this behavior disappears.

I need to know what is causing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

try this.. if tabs are at bottom it will work..in manifest..

Comment: sorry, m not allowed to. But if you need any further info regarding understanding of scenario then i can further elaborate.

Comment: Avinazz, have you tried to add android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" in manifest file for childactivity ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following code:

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Let me know the result so that I can get more clarification on the question.

Comment: btw, i have already managed to put the bottom bars intact at their places but that fails for second level childactivity. Again, if i go to other tabs and come back that issue will be vanished. Same case when app sent to background.